# Code speed on summing numbers in Python 2 vs Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I was messing around with various ways to sum all digits of a number with Python and there where 2 ways that seemed to fit my needs.

```
sum(map(int,str(num))) #First Method
def sum_digits(n): #Second Method
    total = 0
    while n != 0:
        total += n%10
        n /= 10
    return total
```

It did not surprise me in Python 2 method one was slower, but what somewhat surprised me when I took the same code into Python 3, the second method actually slowed down. I understand that map was changed in python 3, which seems to explain the speed up of the first method, what I don't understand was the slow down of the second method.

My question is this: Why did the second method slow down? (The second method ran about two times slower in Python 3 then Python 2). My sample data was all numbers which would be considered to be long, but I'm not sure if that affects it.

Comment: Basically, your first line does all the work in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can imagine that by default division is integral in Python 2 and floating-point in Python 3. Even if the floating-point division itself is as fast on modern hardware as integral division is, repackaging a number into floating point format and back (for modulo) might slow things down enough to be noticeable.

Try using `divmod` which was invented specifically for your case.

See also: [a bit of in-depth look into iterating things in Python](http://www.asimihsan.com/presentations/going_faster_with_python/index.html#28), slides 28 and next several.

Comment: Your imagination is correct. `/` means different things in Python 2 and 3. 3's `//` is 2's `/`.

Comment: Thanks for the link  "a bit of in-depth look into iterating things in Python"

Comment: Ah, thank you. I see all I would have to change is n /= 10 to n //= 10 to get the same speed as before. Such a simple thing I overlooked, thank you.